# UIAccelerometer in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I am working in an iPhone application which included accelerometer. I haven't worked with accelerometer till now and I am not familiar with the libraries to be used.

I had gone through the UIAccelerometer library in iPhone but I would like a bit more help. Would anyone refer any tutorials on this topic?

Comment: Attempting to close this as Too Broad.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what do you need in UIAccelerometer. Visit [this link](http://mithin.in/2009/07/28/detecting-a-shake-using-iphone-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Apple's Core Motion framework which reports motion and environmental data, including accelerometer data.

I'm not sure what documentation you have already read through, but I'm including some links that I have found helpful below:

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotionhttps://) is a link to Apple's Core Motion documentation.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_raw_accelerometer_events) is a link to Apple's documentation for getting accelerometer data (via the Core Motion framework).

And [here](https://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/) is a link to a helpful tutorial.